# Text not updating in stacked barchart d3js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2KuZuS5EG5Ebq2m98wEY?p=preview) here where the rectangles in the bar chart update accordingly but the text doesn't for some reason, it worked in d3js v3 and I'm out of ideas as to why it doesn't work.

Here's part of the code that won't work:

```
textOnBar2.transition()
    .duration(600)
    .attr("y", y0.bandwidth()/2+3)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d["x0_"+TEAM])+25})
    .text(function(d) { return formatText(d["x1_"+TEAM])});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by D3 v4 no longer merging nodes from the enter selection into the update selection. From the changelog:

> In addition, [*selection*.append](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_append) no longer merges entering nodes into the update selection; use [*selection*.merge](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_merge) to combine enter and update after a data join.

Therefore, your selection `textOnBar2` will be empty in the event handler causing the transition to not move around any texts as expected.

The solution is to merge the enter selection into the update selection:

```
// Update selection
var textOnBar2 = category.selectAll(".textOnBar2")
  .data(function(d) { return d.results; });

// Keep the enter selection in its own variable.
var textOnBar2Enter = textOnBar2.enter().append("text")
  .attr("fill","#fff")
  .attr("width", function(d) { return x1(d["x1_"+TEAM])- x1(d["x0_"+TEAM]) })
  .attr("height", y0.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", y0.bandwidth()/2+3)
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d["x0_"+TEAM])+5})
  .text(function(d) { return formatText(d["x1_"+TEAM])});

// Merge enter selection into update selection. 
textOnBar2 = textOnBar2.merge(textOnBar2Enter);
```

Have a look at the updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AMf1XRj8VAU5LoOInjzN?p=preview) for a working demo.